# intellij idea невидимые символы

Tags: intellij-idea

подскажите, пожалуйста как в intellij idea включить отображение невидимых символов? Как тут:

[image: пример невидимых символов]

В VScode сделал без проблем, а в идеи что-то не могу найти.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Зайдите в настройки, там в **Editor** -> **General** -> **Appearance** параметр **Show whitespaces**

UPD: Если вдруг параметра не будет тут, можно просто в поиске (в настройках) ввести "*whitespaces*" и быстро найти его.

Comment: Боже, как всё просто. Глупил и искал в первой вкладке, а не в эдиторе. спасибо

Comment: @Данил Если данный ответ является достоверным, то отметьте его как ответ на вопрос